# Border style not working on hover in tailwind

Tags: hover, version, border, tailwind-css

I'm using tailwind v2.1.0 with Laravel v8.12

I am trying to get hover on **a** tag with tailwind classes but its not working

```
<a href="/" class="text-gray-800 border-transparent border-b-2 hover:border-gray-600 hover:text-gray-800 px-3 py-2 text-sm font-medium uppercase">Home</a>
```

when I replace border-transparent with border-gray-100 or any other color, I can see the hover effect.

Initially I don't want any border that's why border-transparent was mentioned.

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 9):

The following classes should do the job:

```
hover:border-gray-700 border-transparent border-2
```

I found my answer from [here](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/67#issuecomment-800419874)

```
<li class="outline-none hover:border-gray-700 border-transparent border-2 hover:border-current" ><a href="#">Info</></li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You just misspelled **border-tranparent**. Should be `border-transparent`

**Edit**: I don't see any issue with your code. Check the [demo](https://play.tailwindcss.com/Hn8kfJ3dxH) of your code.

Comment: sorry that was just typo while typing question